# Using async-await in promises

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

```
.then(async (rows) => {
//some code
response = await sendEmail(email);
}
```

Hello, is it acceptable to make the then method in promises asynchronous if we refer to another interface to send email?

Comment: Yes, this is like returning a promise for the chain. It's fine. Although I would check why you need to mix `.then`. It's usually easier to stick to one or the other promise api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would work, IMO it's bad style to mix `async/await` with promise chaining. Why not just

```
 fooPromise()
  .then(rows => {
    ...
    return sendEmail(email);
  })
  .then(response => {
    ...
  })
```

or

```
async function foo() {
   const rows = await fooPromise();
   ...
   const response = await sendEmail(email);
   ...
}
```

Ie, chose one way you like better and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer from @derpirscher. The async/await syntax is mostly just syntactic sugar for promises but it can do wonders for legibility. Also you can try:

```
async function doSomething() {
let response;
try {
    response = await sendEmail(email);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return []
}
return response
```

You can find a [resource about async javascript and promises here](https://blog.redsauce.net/javascript-promises).